# Program for playing around with aperiodic tilings

Tags: math-software, tiling

I know this is technically a software question, but I figure the mathematicians here would know more about it:

I'm looking for software to play around with different "paintings" (different patterns drawn *on* the base tiles) of aperiodic tilings such as the Penrose "rhomb" tiling and the Ammann Beenker tiling.

It would be nice, for example, to be able to draw different patterns on sample tiles then automatically see how that'd extrapolate across the plain.

Anyone know of something that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Not software but code: http://ask.sagemath.org/question/9455/penrose-tilings-with-sage/

I imagine you look for something more 'artistic' than this, though http://stephencollins.net/penrose/#Penrose